# "pygame.error: No available video device" on Repl

Tags: python, pygame, replit

I keep receiving Error: `pygame.error: No available video device`.
This works on python default IDLE that comes when installing python 3.10 on Windows but doesn't work with Replit(Online IDLE).

I installed pygame into Relpit as you can see
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwkR2.png)

I'm getting Error from this part of the code:

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT =  800, 800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))  <<<-- ERROR LINE
pygame.display.set_caption("Planet Simulation")
```

This is the the Output:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.12)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.error: No available video device
```

So my question is, Is this the IDLE fault or is the code wrong. Also How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Find the PyGame template when making a new repl]

With replit you have to make sure to use the provided pygame template - which you can search for from the link provided - when creating a "special project" so simply:

1. Make a new project
2. Select the PyGame [template](https://replit.com/templates)
3. copy your code into the new project

and it should fix it!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have ever used replit you would know that this answer is not unclear

Comment: I've been using replit and the answer was enough to let me know what the problem was- I didn't realise there were so many templates just for Python.  To further confuse the issue, I had been using the "standard" Python template for months now and adding the pygame package - with success - until recently I also began to receive this error.